# Excel VBA Checkboxes - Need to Export Values to Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm a newbie teaching myself VBA and I have some basic code that I'm using. I've got the basics of everything except the checkboxes. I've tried different things but I keep running into issues. All I want is for the user to check one or both checkboxes and for the results to appear in a new line. Below is the code and the image that shows the interface (userform).

[example Userform (Interface)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdPOt.png)

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    'To select check box.
   CheckBox1.Value = True
    
    'To select check box.
    CheckBox1.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    'To select check box.
    CheckBox2.Value = True
    
    'To select check box.
    CheckBox2.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub cboClass_DropButtonClick()
    'Populate control.
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Amphibian"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Bird"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Fish"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Mammal"
    Me.cboClass.AddItem "Reptile"
    
End Sub


Private Sub cboConservationStatus_DropButtonClick()
    'Populate control.
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "Endangered"
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "Extirpated"
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "Historic"
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "Special concern"
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "Stable"
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "Threatened"
    Me.cboConservationStatus.AddItem "WAP"

End Sub

Private Sub cboSex_DropButtonClick()
    'Populate control.
    Me.cboSex.AddItem "Female"
    Me.cboSex.AddItem "Male"
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Animals")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboClass.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtName.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtTagNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSpecies.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboSex.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboConservationStatus.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtComment.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.CheckBox1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.CheckBox2.Value
        
    End With
    
    'Clear input controls.
    Me.cboClass.Value = ""
    Me.txtName.Value = ""
    Me.txtTagNumber.Value = ""
    Me.txtSpecies.Value = ""
    Me.cboSex.Value = ""
    Me.cboConservationStatus.Value = ""
    Me.txtComment.Value = ""
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = ""
    Me.CheckBox2.Value = ""
        
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    'Close UserForm.
    Unload Me
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: What you have there should output the value of the checkbox to the sheet, though they will always be false because your checkbox code forces them to be false, there probably shouldn't be anything in the ```CheckBox1_Click()``` and ```CheckBox2_Click()``` subs.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. My only other question is this: how do I change the results so that TRUE returns a tick mark ("x") and FALSE returns a null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the checkbox subs returning false remove the subs or remove everything inside them, toggling between values is inherent functionality of the boxes.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

End Sub
```

To dictate what they output use if statements:

```
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboClass.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtName.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtTagNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSpecies.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboSex.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboConservationStatus.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtComment.Value
        if Me.CheckBox1.Value = True then
            .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = "X"
        end if
        if Me.CheckBox2.Value = True then
            .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = "X"
        end if
        
    End With
```

If you want it to actually say "NULL" instead of an empty cell then before the `end if` place:

```
else
    .cells(lRow, 8).value = "NULL"
end if 'Not a second end if same one as above
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!